# How to pass user id in table from controller Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been struggling all day to pass a user ID from a current user in my application to the sensors table when i create my new sensor

In the sensor Controller i have this code

```
def create
  @sensor = Sensor.new(sensor_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @sensor.save
      format.html { redirect_to @sensor, notice: 'Sensor was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @sensor }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @sensor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def sensor_params
  params.require(:sensor).permit(:name, :typeOfSensor, :privacy,:user_id)
end
```

I have used this code

```
 @sensor = current_user.sensors.build(:current_user_id => params[:current_user_id])
```

But it passes only the id inside the sensor table without the rest of the attributes

How is the correct way to merge the code so that it passes all the parameters (name, typeOfSensor etc and also it passes the id of the user that created this sensor

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure you need the current_user_id from params? you already have the current user, using a param for that is dangerous, a user con edit your code and create a sensor for another user.

justo do

```
current_user.sensors.build(sensor_params)
```

and you are done

Answer (score 0):

Merge is indeed the answer.

```
sensor_params.merge(current_user_id: current_user.id)
```

Comment: Where exactly should i add this code? I tried adding this here
      @sensor = Sensor.new(sensor_params.merge(current_user_id: current_user.id)) but it still didnt add the user id in the table

Comment: What's the schema for your sensors table? Does it have a current_user_id column?

Comment: Dont worry James, mr.arieljuod made it clear for me :) thanks for helping though